# how to Add titles and descriptions to videos on YouTube in other languages using api v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I had studied hardly the documentation on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#november-19-2015 about how to Set localized titles and descriptions.

But when you try it, it seems impossible, even if you use the "app" of the api on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#prubalo you always get the same error with the parameter part. I set that parameter with the value "snippet", like you have to do. But it doesn't work, I tried with the rest of values or possible combinations and..it doesn't work.

Can someone give me an example of the code (i prefer python) or the request http ??
Please be sure you code o request http really works...even i found any mistakes on the examples on the documentation like 5 opening parenthesis and 4 closing parenthesis...

Answer (score 0):

Following is an PHP code example. The concept is same, hope you can do it in the Phython.

Please make sure you set the default language of the video (snippet.defaultLanguage) before adding localisations.

```
// Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
// Part should be 'localizations' not 'snippet' because you are updating the localisation
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('localizations', array('id' => 'YOUR_VIDEO_ID'));

// Since the request specified a video ID, the response only contains one video resource.
$video = $listResponse[0];

// Set the localisations array for the video localisation
// You can retrieve the language list from following API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/i18nLanguages/list
$video['localizations'] = array(
                  'ta' => array(
                       'title' => 'TITLE_IN_GIVEN_LANG',
                       'description' => 'DESC_IN_GIVEN_LANG'));

// Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method.
$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update('localizations', $video);
```

**Update** - Example of updating localisation of video using google developer console

[image: Updating video localisation]

Comment: thanks but....really...every way to try it doesnt work in python. Even the app online you can use from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#prubalo doesnt work....

Comment: @jotajotavm Can you provide the request you are trying in google developer console (a screenshot also enough), I'll try if I can help you

Comment: of course, the following screenshots are about my request https://gyazo.com/b7a39f9233740d5a20b15dfe406e0655 https://gyazo.com/461d122fa5b51e4212fdd7525066e3f8 and the following screenshots are about the result https://gyazo.com/308a1954a8df8b1dd2fa48cbcd12f39a https://gyazo.com/069bd1c4a9ec296b2cbd80f6d5348cb2  thanks for the help

Comment: @jotajotavm The issue with your request is your trying to update both `snippet` & `localisations` parameter together. Try updating them separately. Updated the answer for example screenshot